# Block iTunes from creating the /Music/iTunes/Album Artwok/Cache folder

Tags: macos, itunes

I don't use iTunes and I won't ever. How do I block iTunes from creating the folder `~/Music/iTunes/Album Artwork/Cache`?. I can't find the background process that is responsible for it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you don't wish to uninstall itunes ?

Comment: @mic84: I already uninstalled iTunes, the folder kept appearing.

Comment: I don't tink your issue is fixed. I don't have QL Folder Xray enabled, and the folder is created anyway. Try again later (not every time you use QL on an MP3 with cover art the folder is created).

Answer (score 1):

Remove write permissions from yourself.

Terminal:

`chmod 500 ~/Music/iTunes/Album\ Artwork/Cache`

Comment: He doesn't want the folder to exist. Creating it to withdraw permissions might sound counterintuitive in this case.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately your solution does not work. I fixed my problem by disabling quicklook on folders using the following command in the terminal: defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableXRayFolders 0

Answer (score 0):

It is also created when QuickLooking an MP3 file (not always, but twice for me in two hours) -- I'd say it's futile (if it's just QuickLook, you can workaround that using Finder Get Info preview).